# Check if property exist (Lexical error _ after .)

Tags: velocity, template-engine, vtl

I have this snippet that's causing lexical error

```
#if( $context.args.input._publics )
  $util.unauthorized()
#end
```

The error message is

```
Lexical error,   Encountered: \"_\" (95), after : \".\"
```

How do I check if property `_publics` exists at `$context.args.input`? I can't change the name `_publics`

Comment: This will help you from most of the mess : http://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/generic/EscapeTool.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Velocity 1.7 bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELOCITY-830), which has been fixed in 2.0.

To work around it, you can do:

```
#if( $context.args.input.containsKey('_publics') )
    $util.unauthorized()
#end
```